# Backbone error handling

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I use backbone library

The server requires an authorization for each request

So, any request to the server can returns 401 error

How handle 401 error after `fetch()` calling in the Model and recall `fetch()` with the same options?

I have use the error handler in the Model:

```
var Stores = Backbone.Collection.extend({
initialize: function(models, options) {
    var self = this;
    this.options = options;
    this.on({
        'error': function(model, xhr, options) {
            if (xhr.status == 401) { // Not authorized
                API.restoreToken(function() {
                    self.fetch(options);
                });
            }
        }
    });
}
});
```

but the problem is as follows: when I call `self.fetch(options);`, the object `options` has wrapped `success` function.
So, `self.fetch(options);` doesn't call original `success` function

Answer (score 2):

> The server requires an authorization for each request

This look like a global thing so using `$.ajaxPrefilter()` would suit very well. Quoting from 
[here](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajaxprefilter/)

> **Description:** Handle custom Ajax options or modify existing options before each request is sent and before they are processed by `$.ajax()`.

For example remaking error function of every ajax request

```
$.ajaxPrefilter(function(options, originalOptions, jqXHR) {
  // Save original function
  var originalError = options.error
  // Let's hack
  options.error = function(ejqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
    if(ejqXHR.status == 401) {
      API.restoreToken(function() {
        //Do magic, probably reAjax with options
        //Probably add anti-infinite-ajax mechanism
      });
    }else{ 
      //If not 401 handle it originally
      originalError(ejqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
    }    
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use `self.fetch(self.options)`;

Comment: `self.options` - is member of Model object, it was passed while creation of model object